# Is it possible to call a JavaScript function using an array of values as arguments?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm looking for another way of doing the following:

```
function call_any_function(func, parameters){
    // func => any given function
    if(parameters.length==0){ func(); }    
    if(parameters.length==1){ func(parameters[0]); }    
    if(parameters.length==2){ func(parameters[0], parameters[1]); }    
    if(parameters.length==3){ func(parameters[0], parameters[1], parameters[2]); }    
    if(parameters.length==4){ func(parameters[0], parameters[1], parameters[2], parameters[3]); }
    // ... and so on
};
```

It seems basic but I couldn't find an answer.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh, yes:

```
func.apply({}, parameters)
```

the first parameter is what you want `this` to be inside the function.

Comment: Stupid question, simple answer. Thanks!

Comment: There are no stupid questions, only insanely cool javascript features :)